# Highlighting a point (or an offset) in a file instead of a region

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse plug-in, and I want to highlight some points (between two consecutive characters in a file) instead of a region of text.
As an example, suppose that I want to highlight the position where `foo` has been deleted in a source file.

I know about the Markers([link](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html)), and I can set an annotation to a point in file, which can be shown in the side ruler areas.

Would there be any way to make it visible directly within the editor area itself?
It's obvious to highlight an area of text using something like boxes, underlines, but I couldn't find anything for a single point.

It would be nice if I could draw something like a caret, or a text cursor mark to some of the points I want to highlight.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid annotations is the only civilized way to do it. You can apply them without markers as markers only simplify annotations management and provide persistence mechanism. All depends on how you get the information on what to highlight. Any more details on that?

If you're looking only for a way to customize annotation painting there's no way to do it via API. See in AnnotationPainter.getDecoration(), this is where the stuff happens. Looks like you can customize it only if you provide your own editor. More here - http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/102865/.

Comment: I'm already using the `IMarker` to manage the highlights, because they are all associated with files in projects. I might have to look closely to the way the squiggly lines, boxes are drawn for those markers/annotations.